# How to wait completion of asynchronous processing on website with curl command (or something)

Tags: html, curl

I tried to get a website's HTML body with curl command (I excuted the command in terminal). However, the website uses asynchronous process to return HTML body, so I can get only some HTML like "loading".

Can I wait completion of the asynchronous process to get HTML body using curl command or something?

Comment: please give more details. you said 'curl', is it curl from php? or from bash console? or curl programming language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(programming_language) ? or just javascript/jquery ajax? just specifying cUrl is not specific enough (wikipedia said cUrl us supported in 50 languages)

Comment: @Kristian Thanks, I updated the question. I do the command in terminal. Is this update enough?

Comment: curl only support making 1 http request. not rendering them (and executing javascript, loading assets and making additional request for each http objects). If you need to get data from website, try using web scrapers/crawlers instead.

Comment: @Kristian Thanks, then can I have other ways?

Comment: If you need to get data from website, try using web scrapers/crawlers instead (for example, python with selenium webdriver).